# Folder Access Log?

Tags: 14.04, permissions, security, directory

Most of the work I do is in a computer running ubuntu that I access via SSH, which is administered by a colleague of mine. Some of the data I have in a folder is somewhat sensitive and I would like to know if it has been accessed by someone other than me, and in particular by the administrator. Does the system keep any such records?

Thank you.

Comment: accessed via GUI, cli or any?

Comment: Your first line of defense is linux permissions. If linux permissions are not sufficient use encryption as anyone with root access can alter the logs.

Comment: Keep the files on an external USB flash drive, and backed up on your personal work/home computer. Take the files with you. Just remember to properly eject the flash drive when you're done using it. Waiting to see if somebody has accessed the files is too late.